# Cached files... Except: they're not cached

Tags: php, apache, caching, server

So, I've got this problem that is turning me crazy. I'm quite embarrassed to ask this here but I can't help myself. Here's the deal:
Whenever I am changing the contents of any file on my server, it'll take between 3-5 minutes for the change to show up on my website.

This smells like caching, tastes like caching, looks like caching, hell, it's got caching tatooed to its face, but here's the catch: Everyone involved says it's not caching.

- I upload a php-file to my server, content is "hello world"
- I open said file in my browser, it says "hello world"
- I change file content to "foo bar"
- I refresh my browser, file says "hello world" - could still be my fault, maybe client-side caching?
- I open file in another browser, it says "hello world" - no, this can't be csc... right?
- I open file in another browser on another device, it says "hello world" - definitely no csc!
- I change file content to "Hello FooBar"
- I wait for a few minutes, refresh, file says "foo bar" - hell, this looks like caching
- I wait for a few more minutes, refresh, file says "Hello Foo Bar" - this is definitely caching!!!

Ok, so i got in touch with my hoster & asked them if they cached anything. They told me "naaah, we're not" - said they even tried to reproduce my experiment from above and could not reproduce my results...

Well, I can see only four possible scenarios here:

A) I am lying about my browsers cache being turned off (I can rule that out: It is turned off. I even tried another Server I have with the same hoster - it works just fine! So it can't be my Browser-Settings, right?)

B) My hoster is lying about not caching my stuff (Well... Maybe?)

C) My server has developed conscience and free will - he/she then decided to punish me for all the abuse by caching my data whilst hiding this from my hoster (rather improbable, since it's just a plain old Ubuntu machine running Apache)

D) I am missing something

Before I settle on option B, draw my conclusions and just change hoster, I want to make sure it's not option D. Any suggestions what else might be to blame? Ways to definitely find/rule out possible culprits?

I'm very grateful for any ideas

Comment: And what does your .htaccess file say?

Comment: And what do your headers say?